# Does the heat equation have a unique solution with these mixed boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, heat-equation

Does the heat equation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ on the unit square with $\forall 0 \leq x \leq 1: u(x,0)=0$,
$\forall 0 \leq t \leq 1: u(0,t)=0$, $\forall 0 \leq t \leq 1: u_x(1,t)=0$ have a unique solution?

Here's my attempt:

Let $u, v$ be two solutions to the above IBVP. Let $w=u-v$. Then $w$ solves the IBVP, $w_t - w_{xx}=0$
and $w(x)=0$ on the boundary of the unit square (*). By the maximum principle this means that $w \leq 0$. Similar $w \geq 0 $ applying the maximum principle to $-w$. Hence $w=0$ and the solution is unique.

(*) This seems wrong to me. $w$ hasn't been specified on the upper edge of the unit square hasn't been specified so $ w $ need not be $0$ on the entire boundary of the unit square.

So I suspect there is no unique solution.

Also what if instead we had the wave/Laplace equation with these same conditions?

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define $\omega$, you know $\omega(x,0)=0$, $\omega(0,t)=0$, and $\omega_x(1,t)=0$; a priori you cannot state $\omega(1,t)=0$, so you cannot conclude $\omega\equiv 0$ from here.

The usual trick for uniqueness with Neumann (or mixed) boundary condition is to use an **energy method**. We define an auxiliary functional
$$
E = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}u^2 \mathrm{d}x \geq 0,
$$
and observe that if $u$ is a solution to your problem, this energy is dissipated in time:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}
= \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u^2 \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{1} uu_t \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{1} uu_{xx} \mathrm{d}x
= \left[uu_{x}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int_{0}^{1} (u_{x})^2 \mathrm{d}x
\leq 0.
\end{align}
Now, you define $\omega=u-v$, and study what happens to its energy. From this you will be able to conclude $\omega\equiv 0$, like you wanted, and show uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful to me. Do you know how I would approach the question if instead the PDE was the wave/ poisson equation?

Comment: You can use energy methods for many different PDEs, including the wave equation and the Poisson equation. For the wave equation, you define a different energy, using $u_t$ instead of $u$. For the Poisson equation, you don't look at the *evolution in time* of an energy; rather, you look at an energy which lets you prove $\omega\equiv 0$ directly, see, for instance: http://www.eng.fsu.edu/~dommelen/pdes/style_a/em.html

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.